# Get the particular string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need the particular string in variable for example

```
var teststring = 'asdfgh"Id":123,wdsvvrfwe';
```

I need to get the value 123 from the above string.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: need more examples of string and expected outputs

Comment: provide few more examples.

Comment: Hi sharma thanks, here i got the only option is in that string i will get the "Id":XXX, i need to get the "XXX" from the string. the string may vary in length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just grab any numbers from the string, use this:

```
var teststring = "asdfgh\"Id\":123,wdsvvrfwe"; 
var value = /\d+/.exec(teststring)
console.log(value[0])
```

Or, if you want to grab all values from "Id": up to the comma, use:

```
var teststring = "asdfgh\"Id\":123,wdsvvrfwe"; 
var value = /Id\":([^,]+),/.exec(teststring)
console.log(value[1])
```

Both give:

```
123
```

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/goz/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to extract a `number` from a `string`. Use regular expression: `\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
parseInt(teststring);
```